# Jenkins unable to install plugins on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to configure Jenkins for a project of mine, the problem is that on the Ubuntu VM that I am trying to set this up, the Jenkins installation goes just fine, however, it is unable to download any of the Jenkins plugins.
I tried to disable the firewall as well on the Ubuntu machine but that also does not bring any luck, Same files are downloadable from my local mac which is on the same network:

e.g. I tried

```
curl http://ftp-chi.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/command-launcher/1.2/command-launcher.hpi 

"curl: (52) Empty reply from server”
```

And wget returns:

```
--2018-04-05 10:20:16--  (try: 3)  http://ftp-chi.osuosl.org/pub/jenkins/plugins/command-launcher/1.2/command-launcher.hpi
Connecting to ftp-chi.osuosl.org (ftp-chi.osuosl.org)|64.50.236.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting the response... No data received.
```

I am unsure what could be the reason when both the machines are on the same network and firewall isn't blocking it either.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: check that you are runing behind a proxy and it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those proxy information might not be available to the java instance running Jenkins. Make sure at least http(s)_proxy are set.
Typically, you would fill those proxy data in the Jenkins advanced tab of the proxy manager:

[image: http://blogs.wandisco.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/jenkins-32.png]

The [OP vaibhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589490/vaibhav) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664434/jenkins-unable-to-install-plugins-on-ubuntu/49664493#comment86339457_49664493):

> Downloaded file /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/script-security.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-1, expected 'MYjQw4AV0DWl3AqGU7VV7g/J/Wk=', actual 'TvCHCDNNL1zGA00HjilE2sJe+mE

Make sure to download that plugin not through its URL but with the "available" tab of the Plugin Manager: look for "[Script Security](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin)".

Comment: I added the firewall ip port and other details in the advanced tab of manage jenkins and retried, Downloaded file /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/script-security.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-1, expected 'MYjQw4AV0DWl3AqGU7VV7g/J/Wk=', actual 'TvCHCDNNL1zGA00HjilE2sJe+mE='

Answer (score 1):

I am using  jenkins  in Ubantu on VM. Just Follow the Steps below.
In Terminal Just fire the command as below.

**Installation :**

```
 wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo 
 apt-key add -
 sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable binary/ > 
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

**Updation :**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jenkins
```

Here i give offical refrence [Link](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu) of Installing Jenkins on Ubuntu